# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: 'An error occurred while creating the route with name 'default' and template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am a newbie to the Asp.Net core, and I am just creating a new Asp.Net Core 2 application, but getting as error as preceding.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCreationException: 'An error occurred while creating the route with name 'default' and template '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id=?}'.'

Below is my `Configure` function code.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
            });

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
```

The screenshot of the error is given below.

[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh, it was my mistake. I added an extra character `{id=?}` in the template, instead of `{id?}`. So my working code is looking as preceding.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
            });
```

I read this information from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing), just sharing as it may help someone.